# Particular Windows user restricted to 8.3 format file names on a particular server

Tags: windows, filenames

Our office uses locked down PCs which are prepared off-site and installed by an engineer so I have no insight into the build process.

One colleague had a PC replaced this week and since then he is restricted to 8.3 short file names on a server we store documents on. No one else in the office has this problem.
He can create long file names on his desktop fine so it's not a local policy restricting him to SFN-only.

I can't work out how I would enforce this if I was a server admin.
Any ideas?

[Edit] IT solved the problem. Replacement PC had been created in the wrong Active Directory OU. Now they've moved it, problem has gone away. Still none the wiser what policy was in place.

Answer (score 0):

IT solved the problem. Replacement PC had been created in the wrong Active Directory OU. Now they've moved it, problem has gone away. Still none the wiser what policy was in place.